# Array pattern issue to maintain uniformity

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, tree, distribution

There is an existing array of size 64 that has values 6 values distributed as 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2 3 4 5 ...
Please see the image for complete data. 
The number of occurrence of 0 in the array is 11 times (at every 6th index), 1 is 11 times ... where as 4 and 5 occurs 10 times each.

[image: Array index and values distributed evenly]

There is a necessity to reduce the occurrence of any of these numbers [0 to 5] to a lesser number that could be any number from 0 to 10.

For example, it could be to reduce occurrence of 0 to 6 and 1 to 9. 
I am looking for a solid idea to do this. Certainly all the numbers are to be evenly distributed and not something like 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...

I tried to find the index/position where the reduced value has to filled (64/occurrence of 0 or 2). But at times the index collide with each other and thus is not robust one.

From the example I quoted above, number of occurrence of 0 must be changed to 6 and occurrence of 1 to 9, the result after my algorithm is below -

New location to fill 0 = (Array size)/(new occurrence of 0) = 64/6 = ~10th index
New location to fill 1 = (Array size)/(new occurrence of 1) = 64/9 = ~7 index

For filling 6 0's and 9 1's, first the array is reset after which each of the values are filled to maintain balanced distribution.

After filling 6 0's, the array would be come like this:
[image: Array after filling just 6 0's]

Then, after filling 9 1's, the array would be come like this:
[image: Array after filling just 9 1's]

The index at 55 already has value 0 and apparently 8th 1 also index to 55 that creates a collision. So I believe, this algorithm to balance the distribution does not work. 
How do I populate 6 's, 9 1's and rest of the numbers {2, 3, 4, 5} in the array in a balanced way?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your problem, neither you example " it could be to reduce occurrence of 0 to 5 and 2 to 8". It could be helpful to show one of your solutions and to show where the index collision happens.

Comment: I think that you need to define the problem better. It's not clear what your constraints are. What is an example of an acceptable distribution? Let's say you reduce the occurrence of  `3`: then you could replace the first `3` by a `0`, the second `3` by `1` and so on. Would that result in an acceptable distribution of numbers? I think you need to find a less vague notion for your distribution rather than "evenly distributed".

Comment: @ReinhardMänner, the question is rephrased with an example. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: @Ash the question is rephrased with an example. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Thanks for adding an example, but I am still worried: As @Ash said: What is an acceptable distribution? In your 2nd example, the 1's have first a distance of 8, and later one of 7. This seems to be acceptable to you. What else?